# Issue with calling function to replace certain substrings with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this (this is an example of the problem):

```
let s = `import {
    A,
    B
} from 'moduleA';
import {
    C,
    D
} from 'moduleB';`;
```

And I need to change the names of all modules via function. The names of the modules I get programmatically.

```
let regExpStr = "^import [\\s\\S\\w]* from '(moduleA|moduleB)';";
let regExp = new RegExp(regExpStr, "gm");
let data = s.replace(regExp, function(param, p1, p2) {
    return param.replace(p1, "modified " + p1);
});
console.log(data);
```

And this is the output:

```
import {
    A,
    B
} from 'moduleA';
import {
    C,
    D
} from 'modified moduleB';
```

As you see I modified only `moduleB` but not `moduleA`. What is wrong with my regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The greedy `*` makes the regex capture the whole string, replacing only the last module. Using the non-greedy quantifier `*?` enables the regex to match multiple instances of the `import { ... } from 'moduleN'` pattern throughout the string:

```js
let s = `import {
    A,
    B
} from 'moduleA';
import {
    C,
    D
} from 'moduleB';`;

let regExpStr = "^import [\\s\\S\\w]*? from '(moduleA|moduleB)';";
let regExp = new RegExp(regExpStr, "gm");
let data = s.replace(regExp, function(param, p1, p2) {
    return param.replace(p1, "modified " + p1);
});
console.log(data);
```

I'd also encourage use of the regex literal and dollar-sign capture group references to simplify your code:

```js
const s = `import {
    A,
    B
} from 'moduleA';
import {
    C,
    D
} from 'moduleB';`;

const pattern = /^(import [\s\S\w]*? from ')(moduleA|moduleB)(';)/gm;
const data = s.replace(pattern, "$1modified $2$3");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: It seems to work and with `^`. The problem was in `*?`

Comment: You're right--with the `m` flag, the `^` anchors to the beginning of line rather than the entire string, so it's not the problem.